# How to override margin and right/left in css?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with this styling:

```
#slogan{
    font-size:24px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

The latter 4 styles just center the div content on the page.

If the page gets too big, I don't want to use the following styling anymore, so I apply this style:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 941px){
    #slogan {
        font-size: 24px;
        position: absolute;
        min-width: 810px;
        text-align: right;
    }
}
```

Which displays the content a certain amount from the left edge of the page. I tested these styles in the f12 dev tool, and it looks right. However, when I apply the style inside the css sheet, the margin and right/left parts get still applied to the element, and I don't know how to cancel them (there is no default value for margin).

Any help?

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? Any explanations?

Comment: If you don't want a margin, Just give it a 0 margin...

Comment: jsfiddle would help to understand what problem you're trying to solve

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xsyoLt03/ Here is the fiddle - the problem still stays. I am to remove all margin from the first #slogan, then it displays properly in the @media, but if it stays, no override works

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`unset`, `inherit` or `initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/margin) to unset it.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 941px){
    #slogan {
        font-size: 24px;
        position: absolute;
        min-width: 810px;
        text-align: right;
        margin-left: initial;
        margin-right: initial;
    }
}
```

Here are some global values

```
  /* Global values */
  margin: inherit;
  margin: initial;
  margin: unset;
```

Comment: Invalid attribute for margin

Comment: Setting it to auto did the trick for me. Inital only sets it to, well, inital, which I assume is "0". Disabling the margin-left trough the inspector however did the trick. I had to override a margin-left for a margin-right to take effect.

Answer (score 7):

You could try:

```
margin-left: unset;
margin-right: unset;
```

But I am not sure how well supported they are.
Alternatively set them to 0 which is the default;

Answer (score 1):

if u want to overwrite the css then u have to use !important after attribute like below :--

```
#slogan{
    font-size:24px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin-left:auto !important;//Whatever u want to overwrite
    margin-right:auto !important;
}
```

Comment: But that't the thing, there is no value that I want to override it to. I want to remove those values

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception

Answer (score 1):

you could also set @media the other way

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 941px){
   #slogan {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;}
  }
```